# How to make sticker pack for Whatsapp in Xamarin Forms using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, whatsapp

is it possible to create a sticker pack for Whatsapp in Xamarin Forms?

I tried looking the api provided from whatsapp, but it's only written in swift or obj-c

Comment: About making sticker pack for Whatsapp in Xamarin.form, you can take a look this:https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/blob/master/iOS/README.md